# Terraform CDKTF: How to use/import CDKTF code in existing terraform project?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-cdk

What:- I have a terraform project. In this project, I am creating CI/CD pipeline using codebuild. For manual approvals, I am sending notifications to slack and getting approval on slack. For approvals, I am using Lambda.

As a project requirement, I need to use typescript with lambda. So deploying lambda with terraform is easy but with typescript looks difficult.

- I got a suggestion that using CDKTF will be easy for creating lambda with typescript.
- I don't want to run 2 different projects( CDKTF just for lambda ), is there a way to use the code generated by CDKTF in my existing terraform project because as per my understanding CDKTF will generate code that is understandable by terraform?

I am new to CDKTF, so if any detail is missing feel free to ask! I am not fixed with CDKTF, anything which helps me to integrate typescript/lambda with terraform is welcome

Comment: CDKTF would be no easier for managing an AWS Lambda. It would be relative to team factors such as personal preference and existing skillset.

Comment: Then what do you suggest? What would be easy to manage?

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your CDKTF code / construct to Terraform Module code and use the resulting Terraform Module in your HCL. This [documentation page](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/develop-custom-constructs/publishing-and-distribution#translate-constructs-to-terraform-modules) explains the process.

Comment: Is it possible to show a working example? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/cdktf/cdktf-assets-stacks-lambda

I am trying this